# How can I run this code without defining x and y in my program?

Tags: c

So, the question was find the greatest number using "if" statement between three numbers. I wrote the program myself and I'm a newbie to programming so, I tried to run this program but it showed 2 errors repeatedly.
error 1: x is undefined
error 2: y is undefined

So, I understand that it wants me to define the value of x,y but what I want to do is to firstly Compare the value of a and b and then compare the value of c with the greater number I got by comparing a and b.
I'm pasting my code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b,c;
printf("enter any three number::");
scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
if(x=(a>b)||(b>a));
printf("\n(a>b)||(b>a)=%d",&x);
{
if(y=(x>c)||(c>x));
printf("\n(y>c)||(c>y)=%d",&y);
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

How can I improvise this? Hoping for positive response!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you never defined `x` and `y`, as your compiler pointer out. Just define them like you did for other variables.

```
  int a,b,c,x,y;
```

would do the job.

That said

- you don't really need those `if` statements, as you used here.
- The result of the relational operators (`<` / `>`) are not the numbers, it's an integer value, either `0` or `1`.
- For `%d`, you don't need to supply the address of the variable, just the variable is enough.

Comment: more problems: all `if` have a `;`

Comment: I tried to do that but the compiler showed 2 warnings and didn't let me run the program. Both warnings were something like it is not possible to run that code. The compiler I use is Turbo c++